# Default parameter in function to a reference in c++ unordered_map

Tags: javascript, c++, unordered-map, memoization

I am a JS dev and to implement this function header,I do :

```
function gridTraveler(m,n,memo={})
```

Here,I know that the object would be passed by reference in JS.

So in C++,I decided to do:

```
int gridTraveler(int m,int n,std::unordered_map<int,int>& memo = {})
```

But I get an error : "initial reference to a non const must be an lvalue".

How should I pass the default parameter to the function as well as pass the hasmap by reference?

NOTE:I would be editing the memo object by adding in keys and value in the function body

Comment: What would be the lifetime of that hashmap, who is responsible for removing it? "It should be cleaned up automatically when it's no longer needed." is not an option in C++, as there is no garbage collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you meant can probably be achieved by a two-arg overload that takes care of the unordered map lifetime.

```
int gridTraveler(int m,int n,std::unordered_map<int,int>& memo) {
    //your implementation here
}

int gridTraveler(int m, int n) {
    std::unordered_map<int,int> memo = {};
    return gridTraveler(m, n, memo);
}
```

Comment: @VerilogCoder depends on what you are doing. For one run it is ok. If the call produces something that could be reused for further computation, you would be better off letting the caller manage the map and/or making it global altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Consider explicitly telling it what you really want or creating multiple functions- one that takes a map or one that doesn't.

Possibility 1: You want to sometimes provide a map, but the map serves no operational value; it's just some optional output.  C++ does its best to prevent NULL values as references so use a pointer.  Adding values to a throwaway map would also be silly if you didn't really need to.

```
int gridTraveler(int m,int n,std::unordered_map<int,int>* const memo = nullptr)
{
//code stuff for operation
  if(memo) //optional output related operations occur if it was provided
  {
    //populate memo if it is available
  }
}
```

Possibility 2: You want to sometimes output a map that is internally used in operations.  When it is not provided, you want to use an empty map as the value and throw it away after.  You need a map for your operation but it's a byproduct and you only sometimes care about its values.

```
int gridTraveler(int m,int n,std::unordered_map<int,int>& memo)
{
//do your thing...
}
int gridTraveler(int m,int n)
{
std::unordered_map<int,int> memo;
const int returnval = gridTraveler(m,n,memo);
//last chance to do something with memo here before it gets thrown out
return returnval;
}
```

There are a lot of other possibilities- I can think of scenarios where the map would be best implemented class member with gridTraveler being a function of the class and where the map would be in a global scope, only initialized once to empty map per process.

Answer (score 0):

You can not make a reference on a tempory value. 
Here: `std::unordered_map<int, int>& memo = {} //The "{}" is a tempory value`
Use `const std::unordered_map<int, int>& memo = {}` or use a value without the "&".

Comment: wouldn't the const make it immutable?I would want to insert key value pairs.Also I need to pass the reference to further recursive calls

Comment: Yes, that's right. You can use a smart pointer, a global object (and referencing to this) or do it like below.